# Google App Engine: Using Remote API with a Local GAE Dev Server

Tags: google-app-engine, go, remoteapi, google-app-engine-go

I have a non-GAE backend that's using the Remote API to access datastore. The only way to do this (without a proxy GAE service) is to use the GAE Remote API.

This works fine when connecting the Remote Context to a GAE production deployment, but what about GAE dev server?

I want to be able to test my changes locally before deploying anything. Is there a way to connect the remote API to a local GAE dev server datastore?

Relevant sample code:

```
func getRemoteCtx(ctx context.Context, r *http.Request) (context.Context, error) {
    ts, err := google.DefaultTokenSource(ctx,
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.apis",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    hc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)

    host := "myapp.appspot.com"

    log.Printf("create remote context with host: %s", host)
    return remote_api.NewRemoteContext(host, hc)
}
```

Check out the `host`. Is there a way to set this to a local GAE dev server?

Comment: I usually try not to give advice if it does not answer the question, but I see that no one has answered. Using remote_api_shell for production doesn't seem like a very good idea. Why not just create a handler to deal with that specific task?

Comment: @MeLight thanks! Why do you thing remote api is not a good idea to be used in production? Anyways, there is no one specific task, I need a way to query different entities from the datastore.

Comment: Because remote API requires you to have the App Engine installed on the machine calling the API, _and_ the code of the models. You will need to keep both up to date. Huge hassle. The better approach would be to make a handler to perform whatever task you need - you can pass parameters in the GET request. That way your called application is not dependent on the code of your app and you can trigger it from any app that can make a HTTP request.

Comment: @MeLight good point